# javascript undefined variable inside setInterval that is inside function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am having a problem with variable scope. The code below gives me undefined variable error. I could define cursorX directly inside mymodule object. But I guess this is not the right way because I will end up with tens of variables there. Is there any way to declare variable inside mouseTracking?

```
var mymodule = {
    variable1 : false,
    variable2 : false,
    //some more variables

    somefunctionname: function(){

    },

    //some more functions

    mouseTracking: function(){                       
          var cursorX;
          var cursorY;
          document.onmousemove = function(e,cursorX,cursorY){
              cursorX = e.pageX;
              cursorY = e.pageY;                                
          }
          setInterval("mymodule.saveCursor("+cursorX+","+cursorY+")", 300);
    },                 
}
```

Comment: do you realize that `cursorX` and `cursorX` are not going to update in the interval..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are passing your function in `setInterval()` requires that it be in the global scope and it also "freezes" `cursorX` and `cursorY` at their initial values because the string you construct is only built once when the `setInterval()` is first called.  But, `cursorX` and `cursorY` don't even yet have values at that point so that can't be what you want as it won't work.

So, now I'm guessing that you want the `setInterval()` to use the live, most recent values of `cursorX` and `cursorY`.  You can do that with a function reference like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    mymodule.saveCursor(cursorX, cursorY);
}, 300);
```

This will use the most recently saved versions of `cursorX` and `cursorY`, though it looks like you don't necessarily initialize those to anything until the first mousemove event happens.

Comment: @epascarello - I'm not looking at your answer.  I'm trying to figure out what the OP wants.  Their code "freezes the value of cursorX and cursorY at what they originally were.  That was the first solution I offered.  But, then I thought about it some more and decided that that probably isn't what they want because cursorY and cursorX don't even have initial values.  So, based on that, I guessed what the OP wants to do and I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval("mymodule.saveCursor("+cursorX+","+cursorY+")", 300);
```

is actually

```
setInterval("mymodule.saveCursor(undefined,undefined)", 300);
```

it is not going to update over time, it will always be undefined.

You need to use a closure

```
setInterval( function() { mymodule.saveCursor(cursorX,cursorY); }, 300);
```